# Is there a simple, extensible CRUD repository built over hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, repository

I find myself implementing a `RepositoryBase<T>` abstract class that has the usual CRUD operations, and I'm sure many have done this before already. Isn't there a FOSS CRUD repository built over hibernate? Should I start one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Look [here](http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/). You can also check [hades](http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/show/hades). But hades is more towards JPA though you can make it work with hibernate as well.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't really think I was inventing anything new here :) Thanks, I'll check these out.

Comment: One issue I found is a Null Pointer Exception when not using Spring. http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/issues/detail?id=77